# is there any way to connect flutter web with MYSQL database?

Tags: flutter, web

I am trying to work a flutter web app and the question is, can i use MYSQl database as a backend with backend languages and after this can i also host the website on webserver?

Comment: Definitely you can do that. You should wrap your MySQL DB inside a REST API (i.e. Flask, NodeJS, .NET Web API - whatever you want) and just call the endpoints from Flutter web. Then you can grab your Flutter web and host it even on GitHub Pages if you want, or even in your own web server. All that is possible. Good luck!

Comment: roman-jaquez,  thanks for your response sir. and I wanna use PHP to wrap MYSQL DB. can i?

Comment: Sure, you can do it. PHP is still leading, and Laravel is a great framework for it, and totally recommend it. Check this link. https://www.twilio.com/blog/building-and-consuming-a-restful-api-in-laravel-php. Then all you do is use the HTTP Packages available in Flutter to call your REST endpoints.

Comment: thanks. finally, how to use MYSQL for my flutter web?(i.e, should i use the sql plugin or anoher way?

Comment: I'd say don't use the flutter sql plugin as it is not good practice to access the db directly from your app - it's always good to use a service or some kind of wrapper around it, that's why PHP is there, so just access the data in the db via the endpoints you create in PHP.